# Implement Deposit and Withdrawal functionality

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, paypal, stripe-payments

How can i implement Deposit and Withdrawal functionality for registered users on a website (ASP.NET). If you can provide any urls to a possible online payment processor would be great. 
I've looked into the major (paypal, amazon and etc) gateway payment processors and all i can find is documentation for only credit card payment.

Comment: For Stripe, you can process deposits from bank accounts using [ACH](https://stripe.com/docs/ach). You likely want to look into [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) which allows you to process payments and payouts for connected accounts.

Comment: +1 Stripe Connect.  I know you can connect your bank account to then send funds to (as a user, or admin), so i would then assume they allow you the pull funds out as well for creating payments.  but they will definitely need an account on the website

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful starting point. After some detailed analysis and comparisons BrainTree Marketplace (PayPal Service) is better fit for my needs as it is globally accepted.